# What to do if I have a lot of layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is: I haven't done the huge project before (with bunch of activities and layouts). I don't know how the structure should be organize especially for layouts. I try to create folders and put it there but it doesn't work, just underlines elements. I create folders in this way: layout -> new -> directory (see bellow on the screen)

The question is: how to organize layouts? I don't want to have list of all my project layouts in one folder 'layout'.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, all your layouts (for any one configuration) have to be in the same folder. Use naming conventions to organize them.

Answer (score 2):

They all have to be in the 'layout' folder (can be also in 'layout-land', etc).
Subdirectories not allowed.

If this or that part of a layout repeats often in other layouts you can use `<include>` xml tag.